# O que são e como funcionam os valores de width max-content e min-content?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Recentemente me deparei com esses dois valores para o `width` de um elemento, no entanto não entendi como usa-los e para que servem...

***Isso é o que diz a documentação da Mozilla, mas eu não entendi:***

**`max-content`** A largura intríseca preferida. (width: min-content)
                      <sup>------------------------------------------------</sup>
**`min-content`** A largura intríseca mínima preferida. (width: max-content)
                      <sup>-------------------------------------------------------------</sup>

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

> **O que seriam essas valores de fato, e como os elementos se comportam com eles?**
>  
>   Esses valores já são aceitos por todos os browsers?

*Se possível gostaria de um ou dois exemplos didáticos :)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recomendo ler [este artigo](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing/#block-intrinsic).

Primeiro, esta imagem exemplifica bem o funcionamento de min e max content para width(texto em inglês):
[image: Exemplo do uso de Min e Max Content - CSS]

Agora, um código que produz resultado semelhante ao da imagem, baseado no conteúdo disponível em [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/width):

**CSS**:

```
p.douradinho-max {
  background: gold;
  width: -moz-max-content;
}

p.douradinho-min {
  background: gold;
  width: -moz-min-content;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<p class="douradinho-max">A comunidade Mozilla produz diversos softwares incríveis.</p>
Aqui, a largura assume o valor necessário para agrupar todo o texto em uma linha, ou seja, o valor máximo do conteúdo.
<p class="douradinho-min">A comunidade Mozilla produz diversos softwares incríveis.</p>
Aqui, a largura assume o valor da maior palavra da frase("comunidade"), assim, o valor mínimo de largura necessário para agrupar toda a frase.
```

**Resultado:**
[image: Resultado do uso de Max e Min Content]

Comment: Neto está meio confuso o texto... Olha isso *O tamanho menor que uma caixa pode levar que não leva ao estouro que poderia ser evitado escolhendo um tamanho maior.* Não me ajudou muito... E os exemplos que vc linkou são sobre max-width e min-width, não sobre `width: min-content` e `width: max-content`

Comment: Neto nesse caso te sugiro editar a sua resposta remover os exemplos que estão equivocados nela, rever os texto traduzidos acredito pois não fazem sentido está difícil de entender-los. E coloque os novos exemplos direito como código na resposta, use o ícono ao lado do ícone da imagem para incluir o código na sua resposta. Assim fica mais claro e a resposta preserva o conteúdo caso o link externo pare de funcionar

Comment: O texto não ajudou muito, se vc puder explicar o funcionamento dos novos exemplos ai sim ficaria algo interessante. Pois a duvida é entender como esses atributos funcionam quando aplicados no elemento. Só um código como exemplo sem explicação alguma não ajuda muito