# Como fazer uma div ou span ocupar apenas o tamanho do conteudo interno dela?

Tags: css, css3

Como que posso fazer a div ou o span ocupar apenas o espaço de seu conteudo interno?
Quando crio uma div aqui, ela sempre ocupa 100% do espaço.

Tentei isto mas não deu certo:

```
 div{
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed Bold";
    background: #82b6ea;
    width: auto;
    /* flexbox */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    /* comportamento: em linha com wrap */
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    /* conteúdo justificado no centro */
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content:center;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A `div` é um elemento do tipo bloco e por padrão ela ocupa 100% da largura do container. Já o span é um elemento linha, e por default já ocupa apenas o próprio tamanho.

Então no caso da `div` caso vc quera que ela ocupe apenas o próprio tamanho vc pode deixa-la com `display:inline-block`, assim ela fica "hibrida" e fica com características de um elemento `block` e `inline`. Outra opção é usando `min-content` ou `max-content` no `width` dessa `div`, aqui tem mais detalhes [O que são e como funcionam os valores de width max-content e min-content?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/347693/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-como-funcionam-os-valores-de-width-max-content-e-min-content)

Veja o exemplo abaixo para entender melhor.

```css
div,
span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.min {
  width: min-content;
}
div.max {
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div>DIV padrão - Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="ib">DIV inline-block - Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="min">DIV min-content - Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="max">DIV max-content - Lorem ipsum.</div>
<span>SPAN - Lorem ipsum.</span>
```

---

**Outro detalhe**

Um elemento, mesmo que block, quando com `position:absolute`, ou `fixed` também passa a ocupar apenas o tamanho do próprio elemento, pois ele muda seu escopo no fluxo de conteúdo da página. O mesmo acontece quando se usa `float:right` ou `left` na `div`.

```css
div.pos {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
}
div.float {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pos">DIV position:absolute - Lorem ipsum.</div>
<div class="float">DIV float - Lorem ipsum.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direito você deve esta querendo utiliza o css [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/display) com o valor `table` ou `inline-table`

```css
.teste1{ 
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:4px;
}
.teste2{
    display:inline-table;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='teste1'>Meu texto</div>
<div class='teste2'>Meu</div>
<div class='teste2'>texto</div>
```

[Display - Maujor](https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedade-css-display.php)

Answer (score 1):

A princípio basta colocar `display: flex` na div com `width: max-content` ou `min-content` que irá funcionar.

Exemplo:

- HTML

```
<div class='myDiv'>Conteudo</div>
```

- CSS

```
.myDiv {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
}
```

*Dica: Pesquise um pouco mais sobre flex-box, vai te ajudar muito nessas coisas.*