# Como posicionar DIV no texto

Tags: html, html5

Estou tentando colocar uma DIV na mesma linha do texto, quando executo o HTML abaixo, a DIV fica na linha de baixo do texto.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
posicionar essa div <div></div> na mesma linha
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Como faço para essa DIV ficar na mesma linha do texto para formar apenas uma linha?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer uma div ou span ocupar apenas o tamanho do conteudo interno dela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/377043/como-fazer-uma-div-ou-span-ocupar-apenas-o-tamanho-do-conteudo-interno-dela)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui está um exemplo usando o seu código.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 2px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span> posicionar essa div <div></div> na mesma linha</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Há uma propriedade CSS, `display: inline-block;`